# Una traducción para "watching paint dry"

Tags: traducción, expresiones

¿Hay una expresión en español para describir algo muy aburrido?

> Es tan divertido, como ver cómo se seca la pintura

Eso es una traducción literal, pero busco algo más idiomático.

La definición según wiktionary:

> To watch something that has virtually no movement, hence, something very boring.
>  [Observar algo que no tiene ningún movimiento, es decir, algo muy aburrido.]
>   *I expected his new play to be as good as the last, but it was like watching paint dry*
>  [Creía que su nueva obra de teatro sería tan buena como la anterior, pero la nueva es mortal (es como observar la pintura fresca mientras se seca).] 
> Similar to watch paint dry: watch grass grow [ver crecer el pasto].

Comment: Quizás: *es aburrido a morir, te puedes morir de aburrimiento.*

Comment: @aparente001 He mejorado el formato de lo que has añadido. Lo más destacable es que he añadido "no" a la traducción que has aportado para la primera frase. "Observar algo que tiene ningún movimiento" no es idiomático en español. "Observar algo que virtualmente no se mueve" u "Observar algo que virtualmente no tiene movimiento" son otras posibles traducciones más idiomáticas.

Comment: @RubioRic - queda mucho mejor así, gracias.

Comment: He encontrado una expresión, pero solo aplica en determinados ámbitos. Cuando un escrito o un libro [se te cae de las manos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo#By7SbmA) es que es muy aburrido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conozco un par de expresiones idiomáticas que incluyen explícitamente la idea de aburrimiento y que creo que son de amplia difusión geográfica:

1. ***ver llover***

   > *“Es más aburrido que ver llover.”*

(Se refiere a acciones, es decir, a *algo que es aburrido hacer*, quizá excepcionalmente a personas aburridas, pero en el sentido activo, o sea, lo que en inglés se traduce como *boring*, no como *bored*.)

2. ***como una ostra***

   > *“Me aburrí como una ostra.”*

(Se refiere a la persona que sufre el aburrimiento. Hay que imaginar a la persona transformada en un molusco bivalvo inmóvil en el fondo del mar.)

La susodicha ostra puede, para mayor efecto, chupar un clavo (?):

> *Estaba más aburrido que una ostra chupando un clavo.*

Hay cantidades de [expresiones regionales](https://www.duarte.cl/comparaciones-mas-aburrido-que/) también, muchas de las cuales, aunque no sean usuales, son inmediatamente comprensibles y graciosas.

Comment: ... y el golf....

Answer (score 1):

Yo suelo usar "ver crecer la hierba". "ver subir y bajar la marea" pero en el sentido no de algo aburrido sino en el sentido de estar haciendo nada pero como algo de disfrute.